# Slow web service (and WCF service) calls from Windows 7

Tags: wcf, web-services, windows-7, asmx

I am building a .NET 3.5 Winforms app that uses WCF services (wsHttp binding) to communicate to my server which gets data from SQL Server and passes it back to the Winforms app (Smart Client).  I noticed since running Windows 7 RTM there is about a 30 second delay the first time the WCF communicates, from that point forward it's normal as before.

I noticed another application (Desaware licensing system) that uses ASMX services also experiences this same problem, a startup delay then all is fine.

This first time startup is not a .NET complilation/JIT issue, I can close the app right away and do it again.  The server is running Windows 2003/IIS 6.  All was fine prior to Windows 7.

I tried removing my anti-virus software, same issue.  I cannot figure out why there is this initial delay, a significant one at that.  I notice too in the Debug window as the application is starting up a delay as the System.IdentityModel line, it looks as if there is a security/authentication change on Windows 7 I presume that is causing this delay.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  VS 2008 / .NET 3.5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added the following entry into the binding configuration and it appears to have solved the issue.

useDefaultWebProxy="false"

Comment: Wish I could give more than one upvote; this saved my day! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem.  I create my proxy using a ChannelFactory object, and found that in addition to specifying useDefaultWebProxy for the binding server-side, it was also necessary to specify the option client-side:

```
HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
    MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
    AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = false
}
```

I found that the issue only occured when using the current Windows credentials.  If you pass specific credentials then the performance was as expected.  However, setting the UseDefaultWebProxy client side fixed the problem.

Hope this helps someone, somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

A 30 second delay, sounds like it is waiting for something and then timing out after 30 seconds.

It is probably something to do with the authentication between your windows 7 machine and the server. Checking the event log would be a good place to start.

Comment: Next thing then to check is the network. Are both machines in the same domain? Is there a firewall between the machines, or between the machines and the domain controll? Also, test from windows XP, just in case there has been a change in the code.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for my Windows 7 and connecting to a WebServer

useDefaultWebProxy="false"

Thank You
Douglas