# WCF Performance on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have an interesting problem with WCF in a Windows 7 environment... it's slooooooow.

The service is self-hosted, running in a console app.

The same code running in a Vista environment runs in about 1/3 of the time.

Server config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Logging.Services.LoggerServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="nettcp" maxBufferSize="524288" maxConnections="1000" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="Logging.Services.LoggerServiceBehavior" name="Logging.Services.LoggerService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="nettcp"
             name="tcp" contract="Logging.Services.Contracts.ILogger" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8001/LoggerService" />
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8002/LoggerService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client config:

```
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="tcp" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
             transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxBufferSize="524288" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="524288" maxArrayLength="16384"
                 maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                 enabled="false" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>                 
            </binding>              
        </netTcpBinding>
```

and

```
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8001/LoggerService" binding="netTcpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="tcp" contract="LoggerLogService.ILogger"
         name="tcp" />
```

I read somewhere that someone with a similar problem, running NOD32 had to turn HTTP Checking off, which I have done to no effect. I completely disabled NOD with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh... apologies guys, I was pointing my repository at my SQL server at work... Would help if I had noticed the 7MB of error logs available the entire time. Sleep deprivation is finally kicking in I think.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: consider flagging your original post for deletion, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx) to track down where the bottleneck might be occurring.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am only getting 2 calls per second with a large backlog of calls outstanding. This is for a "one way" service call. Weird...

Comment: Sounds like something is slowing them down further upstream, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369694/slow-web-service-and-wcf-service-calls-from-windows-7) try adding the following entry to the binding configuration:

useDefaultWebProxy="false"

**EDIT:**
Since you are using netTCP, try increasing your maxConnections and maxmessagesize

Comment: Hi Russ, the useDefaultWebProxy attribute is for HTTP based bindings only afaik.

Comment: ah, i guess i should pay closer attention

Answer (score 0):

What is the concurrency mode set to on the service?  I'm not sure how to do this through the config file, but on one of my WCF services, I added this ServiceBehaviorAttribute to my service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    Namespace="http://blah.com/",
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
    ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyServiceInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

If your service is already running with concurrency and things are still slow, it may be due to something in the service code itself.  Although Vista is 3 times faster, that still sounds incredibly slow, depending on what the service is doing.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, my service is also a Singleton and has a ConcurrencyMode of Multiple. I did find my problem though, see above.